# How to call network twice in MVVM?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have a call to `Flickr API search` where I get the IDs of the photos with a random tag and now I need to use those IDs to call the `Flickr API getSizes` and get an `Arraylist<String>` with the url photos. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mActivityStartBinding = getViewDataBinding();
    mainViewModel.firstTime().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<String> ids) {
            mainViewModel.firstTime();
            Timber.d("-------MainActivity-------1:");

            mainViewModel.getPhotos(ids);
            Timber.d("-------MainActivity-------2:"++ids.toString());<<-----I'd like to have here the URLs but this will print the ids

        }
    });

}
```

I don't know how can I get the PhotoUrls if I don't put the `mainViewModel.getPhotos(ids);` inside that IF, because I will need the ids from the `mainViewModel.firstTime();`.

Btw, I'm using MVVM approach. Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: With MVVM, the network calls are done in the model layer. How come you're doing them in the view? That's not MVVM.

Comment: @Duos you're right, that was not right, I've change to made it in repository with two Transformation.switchMap but I'm still having problems, because I don't know how to get the ids from the first call.